# :hover для мобильных

Tags: css

Есть обычная конструкция кнопок css с основным цветом и hover. Всё работает, как и положено, но не для мобильных. Там после нажатия на кнопку цвет остаётся в положении hover. И лишь "ткнув" пальцем в экран ещё раз, меняется hover на исходное значение. Как убрать эту недоработку? 
(Всё, что находилось по теме, это проблемы с наработающим значением hover в мобильных. У меня же, как видно, работает, но неправильно). Код ниже.

```css
button{
    position:relative;
    z-index:800;
 background:#fff;
 border:none;
 color:#a88854;
    font-size:16px;
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
 width:48px;
 height:48px;
 cursor:pointer;
 left:0;
    top:0;
    line-height:48px;
 text-align:center;
    outline:none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 -transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
button:hover{
 color:#b8b8b8;
}
```

Comment: а каким образом вы хотите наводить курсор на мобилке ? его же нету там

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88582/discussion-on-question-by---hover--).

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, про курсор ты прав, но вопрос вообще-то интересный.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот по такой схеме:

```css
button {
  color: blue;
}

button:hover {
  color: red;
}

@media (pointer: coarse) {
  button:hover {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Just a button</button>
```

Теоретически, можно было бы сделать как надо, но поддержка браузерами не радует:

```css
button {
  color: blue;
}

@media (pointer: fine) {
  button:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Just a button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ниже скрипт. В десктопной версии он не меняет ничего. Мобильная версия не реагирует на :hover. Что и требовалось доказать. 
Установить скрипт достаточно перед

```js
<script>
function hasTouch() {
    return 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement
           || navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0
           || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0;
}

if (hasTouch()) { // remove all :hover stylesheets
    try { // prevent exception on browsers not supporting DOM styleSheets properly
        for (var si in document.styleSheets) {
            var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[si];
            if (!styleSheet.rules) continue;

            for (var ri = styleSheet.rules.length - 1; ri >= 0; ri--) {
                if (!styleSheet.rules[ri].selectorText) continue;

                if (styleSheet.rules[ri].selectorText.match(':hover')) {
                    styleSheet.deleteRule(ri);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ex) {}
}
</script>
```